# Need assistance regarding viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, calayer

Apple doc regarding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` says:

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view
>   adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this
>   method. However, **this method being called does not indicate that the
>   individual layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted.** Each
>   subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.
>
> **Your view controller can override this method to make changes after the view lays out its subviews.** The default implementation of this
>   method does nothing.

I have `view1` which contains `view2` means `view2` is a subview of `view1`. I am creating a `CALayer` for my `view2` which I want to be exact size of `view2`. I am using `auto layouts` so I want to create the `CALayer` when `auto layout` finish its work so I can have correct values to set for `CALayer` frame.

But in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method I can't detect when exactly `view2` frame is set by `auto layout` because Apple doc is also saying that

> this method being called does not indicate that the individual
>   layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted.

after that Apple doc saying

> Your view controller can override this method to make changes after
>   the view lays out its subviews.

I am so confused at what point `auto layout` will set `view2` frame so I can set my `CALayer` frame accordingly.

Comment: if you just need your layer to be automatically adjust the bounds - just override `layerClass` method to your layer

Comment: @Sega-Zero Please can you provide a small example or snippet, it will be really helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/726712/1254172

Comment: But still I can't figure out when auto layout will finish its work and when my particular view will have its frame and when I can use the frame values (for any purpose).

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the right place to ensure subviews of viewcontroller's view are aligned properly, but it's not the place where you may be sure they're displayed on the screen accordingly. And it is not the place where you may be sure all the subviews of root subviews are aligned - it is a responsibility of the subviews (the docs says it clear enough). Normally, with auto layout you don't need to do any extra work. But you can always override `setFrame:` method to catch the right place for a particular view.

Comment: @Sega-Zero thanks a lot for the help, please post your solution as an answer so I can accept it and up vote it.

Comment: The smart person who down vote my question can please tell me the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you don't have to do anything special if your view is aligned with auto layout. If you want a single layer to adjust its bounds to the view's bounds, the most simple and correct way will be overriding `layerClass` method of the view - in that case layer bounds will be adjusted within a view automatically. If you need one more layer in addition to the standard one, the best place to update layer's bounds may be `setFrame:` method override.

As of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it is just an event to inform you, that all subviews of viewcontroller's root view are positioned at the desired places. You are not guaranteed that all the rest subviews of those subviews will also be aligned, since it is a responsibility of the parent view itself. they can be both auto layout positioned and manual layout positioned. This event also does not guarantee that all the the views are displayed as desired, especially if their frame change is animated.